# Silverlight 4 Canvas Height and Width Binding

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working on silverlight apps and I want to bind the Canvas Width and Height through XAML but how I can bind it.Because the canvas width and height I had tried to bind it but will not working in my case so if you guys have any other binding way to bind it so please put some somple code so I can figure out the solution of this problem.

I wan to bind this with the Image Height and Width so the some times Image size is 1000 x 1200 and some times image size will be 1400 x 1700 so how I can bind it?

```
<Viewbox 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Canvas
                Height="1000"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="1200">

                    <Image x:Name="imgEdit" 
                                Cursor="Hand"
                                MouseLeftButtonDown="imgEdit_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                MouseMove="imgEdit_MouseMove"
                                MouseLeftButtonUp="imgEdit_MouseLeftButtonUp"   
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">

                    <Image.Effect>
                        <l:briconEffect 
                                    Brightness="{Binding ElementName=bVal, Path=Value}"
                                    Contrast="{Binding ElementName=cVal, Path=Value}"
                                    Gamma="{Binding ElementName=gVal,Path=Value}"
                                    RedRatio="{Binding ElementName=rVal,Path=Value}"
                                    BlueRatio="{Binding ElementName=blueVal,Path=Value}"
                                    GreenRatio="{Binding ElementName=greenVal,Path=Value}"/>
                    </Image.Effect>

                    <Image.RenderTransform>

                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotator">
                                <RotateTransform.Angle>
                                    <Binding ElementName="sldVerHorizontal" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                </RotateTransform.Angle>
                            </RotateTransform>

                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="Scale">
                                <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                    <Binding ElementName="sldZoomInOut" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                                    <Binding ElementName="sldZoomInOut" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                            </ScaleTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>

                    </Image.RenderTransform>


                </Image>

                <Border
                        x:Name="maskBorder"
                        MinWidth="200"
                        MinHeight="200"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="5"
                        Canvas.Left="250" 
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        Canvas.Top="250">

                    <Rectangle
                        MinWidth="200"
                        MinHeight="200"
                        x:Name="maskRect"
                        Canvas.Left="250" 
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        Canvas.Top="250">
                    </Rectangle>
                </Border>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Do you mean your Canvas should grow and resize based on the size of the Image ?

Comment: Yes Exactly. I am looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may bind the Canvas Width and Height properties using Element Binding like this

Width={Binding Element=imgEdit,Path=ActualWidth}
Height={Binding Element=imgEdit,Path=ActualHeight}

You may also wrap the Canvas within a ScrollViewer of fixed Width and Height to limit for user screen size.

Comment: Thanks Dear @kanchir: This is working but still my problem is not resolve. because I want to wrap image to the canvas whether it is horizontal image or vertical image. so still you have any other solution for this then I will be more thankfull to you.

Comment: Did you try putting the image within a ScrollViewer like this ? <Canvas><ScrollViewer><Image/><ScrollViewer></Canvas>

Comment: I had tried it but it will not working because I want panning facility so the scrollviewer will not work in between.

Comment: Instead of Canvas did you use a Grid ? Also did you try removing the Height and Width of canvas and set the Horizontal and Vertical Alignment to Stretch for the Canvas ?